# Can I power 3.3V to MEMS mic which is TYP=1.8V?

Tags: microphone, mems

I am reading [this](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IM72D128-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=8ac78c8c80027ecd0180612a60277e10) datasheet.

I have 3.3V for MCU and running out of space in the PCB area. So I want to avoid adding LDO for 1.8V.

In the datasheet, it said `MIN=1.62 TYP=1.8 MAX=3.6`.

Is it better to power this with 1.8 or 3.3 is still OK?

(My 3.3V is from a buck converter, so if it is not stable enough, I might need to add LDO anyway. Not sure.)

Comment: 3.3 V is OK, but an R/C filter of 100 ohm and >= 1µF would be helpful.